# Ideal gas equation and charle's law paradox

Tags: homework-and-exercises, temperature, ideal-gas, volume

The question come in my mind when discussing about a question on ideal gas with my friend. The question sounds like below:

> An open vessel at 300 K is heated till $\frac {2}{5}$ th of the air in it is expelled. Assuming that the volume of the vessel remains constant. If the pressure is constant, what is the temperature to which the vessel is heated?

**So, my first attempt by using charle's law to find out the answer:**

Initial temperature $= T_1 = 300K$

We assume the vessel has no change in its volume.

Let, Final temperature $= T_2$

The volume of air at $T_1 = V_1$

The volume of air at $T_2 = V_2$

According to the question,

$V_2 = V_1 + \frac {2}{5}V_1 = \frac {7}{5}V_1$

Because, $\frac {2}{5}$ th of the air expelled from vessel means air's volume is increased by $\frac {2}{5}$ th of it and the vessel's volume is constant.

According to charle's law,

$\frac {V_1}{T_1} = \frac {V_2}{T_2}$

Or, $\frac {V_1}{300} = \frac {7V_1}{5T_2}$

$\therefore T_2 = 420K$

**Second attempt by using ideal gas equation**:

Ideal gas equation: $PV = nRT$

As, the volume of vessel remains unchanged. Hence, the volume of air in the vessel remains constant.

If $PV = constant$

Then, $nT = constant$

Hence, $n_1T_1 = n_2T_2$

Where $n_1 =$ number of moles of air at $T_1$ and $n_2 =$ number of moles of air at $T_2$

According to the question,

$n_2 = n_1 - \frac {2}{5}n_1 = \frac {3}{5}n_1$

$n_1T_1 = n_2T_2$

Or, $300n_1 = \frac {3}{5}n_1T_2$

$\therefore T_2 = 500K$

Why aren't the results matching?

I don't want to correct me or check my work or solve this. That is just an example of the real problem. But I mentioned it in example because this is a very popular question and it is done in the second method. But I think that is wrong.

I thought the ideal gas equation is used in a wrong way. $V$ actually means the total volume of gas. But in the second method we took just a part of gas which is wrong. The $nT = constant$ relation only holds when the volume of air (gas) is actually constant which is in a closed vessel. And so, the total volume of air remains constant when there are less moles of air but in increased temperature and more moles of air but in decreased temperature. And so, in an open vessel working only with the volume of air in it is a wrong idea when temperature is increased and we have to conclude the total volume made up with the volume in the vessel and the $2/5$ th of air expelled.

Is my reasoning correct or is there any other reason?

Comment: $\frac{2}{5}$th of the air means the amount(moles), not the volume. For charles law, number of moles of the system should not change, here $\frac{2}{5}$ of the gas escapes and  will have a different temperature then the gas remaining inside. For some constant amount of gas, you can't write a final volume having some final temperature as two parts of the gas are at different temperature as one part escapes. Only ideal gas equation is applicable: P,V are constant here, amount of gas(n=no. of moles) and temperature changes: $n1T1=n2T2$.

Comment: There must be equally distribution of moles per volume in a ideal gas

Comment: all the laws like charles law, boyle's law etc are just special cases of ideal gas law where only two quantities out of P,V,T and n are allowed to change and remaining two are constant.  For charles' law: T-V relationship $\Rightarrow$ n and P should remain constant throughout.

Comment: Yes total n and P are constant here for the first case and in the second case n isn't considered constant because we are considering the air in the vessel. And also ideal gas equation is applicable for any conditions of ideal gas.

Comment: yes. So you can't even use charles law to begin with.

Comment: Nope, the conditions are different. At first case we are talking the total gas and in second only the gas in vessel. So, for the first charle's law is applicable

Comment: for a constant amount of gas (n moles), if the entire amount of gas is at the same temperature T1 and having volume V1 then if at a later stage, the same entire amount of gas is at a temperature T2, V1/T1=V2/T2 will hold, where V2 is the final volume. So you need to choose some portion of the gas as your n, and then need to satisfy all these conditions mentioned above, then only you can apply charles law fruitfully. For the scenario in your problem, you can't do any of this for any portion of the gas, well you can write the  equation but you won't be able to extract information.

Comment: (forgot to mention constant P is also required) so pressure when the system is at V1,T1 should be the same as when the system is at V2,T2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139715/discussion-between-debanjan-biswas-and-aman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charle's law is a special case of the ideal gas law. If you assume that $n_1=n_2$ and $P_1=P_2$ you get that $P/T = \text{const}$. So, what's different about the two scenarios is what you're assuming is fixed. In the first case, you're using an expanding container that keeps $n$ fixed. In the second case, you're assuming that $V$ is fixed and $n$ is not. Now, reread the problem to figure out which one applies here: you have a fixed quantity of gas in a container that is changing volume, or you have a container with fixed size that has a variable amount of gas in it?